# continuous hits my webserver with wordpress or Magento request but im not using either

Tags: ddos

I have a PHP website on AWS which is getting bad gateway so I have looked into Nginx server logs and found that an errors

```
connect() to unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream
```

when I looked further I've found there are lots of errors as below which shows WordPress request

```
2020/03/16 04:11:05 [error] 3170#0: *744374 open() "/var/www/mysite.com/public/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/34649/og-image.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), clie$
```

But I don't have WordPress in my server can anyone help, what to be done on this

Comment: welcoming to the internet and bots that want to spam. ignore it. i have couple of thousands request of this per day...

Comment: .. and dont forgot to start yozr php fpm